# Laravel paginate() method is not working with the distinct() method

Tags: php, laravel, distinct, laravel-query-builder, pagination

My Laravel code is something like this...

```
Cheque::distinct()->get(['cheque_no'])->paginate('25');
```

If possible I want to add `sortByDesc('updated_at')` also.
Please help me.

Comment: "is not working"

Answer (score 2):

First off, I think you want

```
distinct('cheque_no')->get()
```

instead of

```
distinct()->get(['cheque_no'])
```

Then, either you use `get` or `paginate`

And you define the sorting at the end

So, the altogether ends up like this:

```
Cheque::distinct('cheque_no')->paginate(25)->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```

Comment: Query is ok. but I'm getting error in view page where my pagination links are.
{{ $paginateData->links() }}